# Display a message if cash on delivery is not available on Checkout page

Tags: magento2, php

I just want to show the message on the checkout page, when COD is not applicable. 
for Eg: if we are adding the minimum order total 500 for COD.

Then any user tries to purchase below 500 then they able to see a message on checkout page. Like: COD not available to on cart value below 500.

Please help me to create this.

Comment: exactly where you want this message in checkout page?

Comment: perhaps it would be better to remove the COD payment method if order total below 500.

Comment: On Checkout page where all payment method show excluding COD.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your custom message on checkout page using following ways, do some customization in code as per your need

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/custom-block</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-block.js

```
define(['jquery', 'ko', 'uiComponent', 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'], function ($, ko, Component, totals) 
{
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend(
    {
        defaults: { template: 'Vendor_Module/custom-block' },
        isDisplayMessage: ko.observable(false),

        initialize: function ()
        {
            this._super();
            var self = this;

            if(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value < 500)
            {
                self.isDisplayMessage(true);                
            }

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/custom-block.html

```
<!-- ko if: (isDisplayMessage()) -->
    <div>
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'COD not available to on cart value below 500'"></span>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You can see in this image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the same code but it's not working. one more things that we need to check COD Available or not then show the message. Ref: http://prntscr.com/r03tbd

Comment: clean cache remove pub/static var/view_preprocessed and try again